# CLI Uninstall Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm having problems with Service Fabric that I can't figure out, so I will try a reinstall. However, I want to do this using the CLI, but I can't even find it in the list of installed packages;)

First trying Get-AppxPackage, which doesn't list either the SDK or the Runtime.

```
Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers
```

I also tried Get-WmiObject and this actually lists the SDK, but not the Runtime.

```
PS C:\Users\caec> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product| Where-Object -Property Name -Match "Fabric"


IdentifyingNumber : {8D646D05-61C0-49AA-98C0-B92AAF1F9119}
Name              : Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK
Vendor            : Microsoft Corporation
Version           : 6.1.1390.9590
Caption           : Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK
```

If I look in installed Apps in Control Panel, I see both.

Any pointers?;)

Answer (score 0):

*I tried installing service fabric CLI in my Azure Bash environment and able to run it successfully after installation.*

*Install* `service fabric` *using below* `pip` *command.*

**Note**: Make sure that you check the `Python, Service Fabric as well as pip version` compatibility.

```bash
pip install -I sfctl==11.2.0 //Latest version
```

[image]

*Once it gets installed successfully, execute below command to check* the `runtime version & compatibility` *as shown*:

```bash
sfctl --h
```

[image]

*Executing below command will take you to the service fabric command line and sub commands.*

```bash
sfctl
```

[image]

[MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli) for reference.